# Ionic 2 - Storage no está almacenando (persistiendo los datos)

Tags: ionic, typescript, local-storage

tengo un problema con Ionic 2, estoy intentando almacenar un token JWT en el Storage de Ionic, pero aunque en el momento lo guarda, al intentar acceder al mismo desde otro componente este viene vació o mejor dicho, ni existe.

Tengo este provider:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { JwtHelper, tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Storejwt {
    private jwtHelper: JwtHelper;

    constructor(private local: Storage) {
        this.jwtHelper = new JwtHelper();
    }

    /**
     * Obtener Dato por Clave desde el Storage
     */
    public getDato(clave: string): any {
        return this.local.get(clave);
    }

    /**
     * Asignar dato a una Clave en el Storage
     */
    public setDato(clave: string, valor: any): any {
        return this.local.set(clave, valor);
    }

    /**
     * Remover Dato por Clave del Storage
     */
    public delDato(clave: string): any {
        return this.local.remove(clave);
    }

    /**
     * Decodificar token en formato JWT
     */
    public decodeToken(token: any): any {
        let rtnData: any = null;

        try {
            rtnData = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(token);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Storejwt Error (decodeToken): ' + e)
        }

        return rtnData;
    }

    /**
     * Verificar si el token a expirado o no (True: aún no ha expirado, False: ya expiró)
     */
    public isActive(token: any) {
        let tk_expired = false;
        try {
            tk_expired = tokenNotExpired(null, token);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Storejwt Error (isActive): ' + e)
        }
        return tk_expired;
    }

}
```

y sí, ya lo agregué a los providers del app.module.ts al igual que el Storage, entonces cuando logueo frente a un API en PHP que me devuelve todo bien, lo almaceno con y cambio el root a HomePage así:

```
this._storeJwt.setDato('id_token', data);
this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
```

El cual ya he importado e inyectado en el constructor, pero por ejemplo desde HomePage si intento hacer esto:

```
this._storeJwt.getDato('id_token');
```

Este viene vacio por lo que para el no está logueado y me saca de la aplicación al LoginPage de nuevo.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda, saber que estoy haciendo más ya que la documentación oficial solo menciona eso que he hecho, incluso ya instale el @ionic/storage (que igual ya estaba por cierto) y ese cordova-sqlite-storage, que para mi caso no es necesario.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La estructura de datos en typescript es un poco complicada con algunas cuestiones, te recomiendo investigar lo que es Promise y Observable en typescript.

En el código de tu almacén pon esto:

```
public getDato(clave: string): any {
    return this.local.get(clave).then((value) => {
        return value();
    });
}
```

Y para llamarlo usa esto:

```
this.storejwt.getDato("clave").then(dato => {
  this.foo = dato;
});
```